# How to filter by category in Magento 2's API?

Tags: rest, magento, magento2

In Magento 2's REST API, there is an option to search a product using various search criteria. As you know, an example is given below:

```
http://magentohost/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%macbook%& searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

But I have not found an option to search by category.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To search by category, it is simple. You have to just pass `category_id` as a field. Have a look at below example:

```
http://magentohost/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id& searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=4& searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at& searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC& searchCriteria[pageSize]=10& searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also target multiple categories at once:

```
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1,2,3&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=in&searchCriteria[sort_orders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sort_orders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[current_page]=1&searchCriteria[page_size]=10
```

I have a little lib - https://github.com/dsheiko/magentosearchquerybuilder, which helps me building such queries

```
$builder = new SearchCriteria();
$builder
    ->filterGroup([
        [ "category_id", implode(",", $categories), SearchCriteria::OP_IN ],
    ])
    ->sortOrder( "created_at", "DESC")
    ->limit(1, 10);


echo $builder->toString();
```